# odbc_result(): Field index is larger than the number of fields?

Tags: php, odbc, intersystems-cache

How do I resolve this error?  I was hoping to get an associative array of the first row of the result without having to name all the columns.

> PHP Warning:  odbc_result(): Field index is larger than the number of
> fields

```
    $sql = "sql query with 14 columns";
    $result = odbc_do($link, $sql) or trigger_error("query failed ".odbc_errormsg(), E_USER_ERROR);
    $details = odbc_fetch_array($result,0);
    return $details;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing 0 with 1

```
odbc_fetch_array($result,0);
```

with

```
odbc_fetch_array($result,1);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).